# Drawing a second text below the first text

Tags: vb.net, itext

I would like to draw 2 texts onto my PDF.
The first text should be aligned to the top left corner.
This works fine.

I'm using:

```
canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(i)
watermarkFont = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.HELVETICA, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CP1252, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
watermarkFontColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED

canvas.MoveTo(0, 0) 'I think the canvas is the space that we draw onto. My documents always start at position X=0 and Y=0, so move to 0,0 should be fine
canvas.BeginText()
canvas.SetFontAndSize(watermarkFont, 12)
canvas.SetColorFill(watermarkFontColor)
canvas.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_TOP, uText, 0, 830, 0) 'is 830 the width of the available space?
canvas.EndText()
```

Now I would like to draw another text approximately 100 pixels below the first text.

I'm using:

```
canvas.MoveTo(0, 100) 'let's draw the second text at X=100, Y=100
canvas.BeginText()
canvas.SetFontAndSize(watermarkFont, 12)
canvas.SetColorFill(watermarkFontColor)
canvas.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, uBewirtung, 0, 830, 0)
canvas.EndText()
```

The second text however doesn't show up at all.
I suspect I'm drawing outside the document, but I don't see my mistake.

Comment: PDF default coordinates are as usual in mathematics, i.e. **y** values rise when going *upwards*. (Applying transformations this can be changed but you did not mention that you had transformed the coordinate system.)

Thus, when drawing text 1 at (0,0) and text 2 at (0, 100), the latter is not drawn *below* but instead *above* text 1. Furthermore the coordinate system origin usually starts in the *lower* left corner of the page (this is not mandatory but very common). Thus, if your first code block really adds text in the upper left corner, you forgot to mention some crucial detail.

Comment: @mkl The info on the rising y values is great! This is my code, I'm not missing anything. The text really is drawn on the top left corner.

Comment: [After another look at your code] ... ah, ok... in `canvas.ShowTextAligned` you have three float parameters, `0, 830, 0`; they are **x**, **y**, and **rotation**. Thus, your `830` is not the width as you wondered, but it is the **y** coordinate at which the text is drawn, and 830 on portrait A4 with origin in the left bottom corner is fairly near the top of the page. BTW, `Element.ALIGN_TOP` does not make sense there, the alignment there can be `ALIGN_CENTER`, `ALIGN_RIGHT` or `ALIGN_LEFT` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MoveTo()` method is meant for drawing paths (lines amd shapes in graphics state), not text (in text state). It adds an `m` operator to the content stream. If you are a PDF specialist, you should use the `SetTextMatrix()` method *inside* your `BT`/`ET` text block: [What does setTextMatrix of contentByte class in iText do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560425/what-does-settextmatrix-of-contentbyte-class-in-itext-do)

Note the *if*; it is important. If you are not a PDF specialist, you shouldn't be toying around with those methods. You should use `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned()` instead of `BeginText()`, `EndText()` and all of the lines you added in-between. Those methods are meant for people who speak PDF syntax.